# Binomial distribution to return an Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, binomial-theorem

Need to Generate a binomial distribution, tested 10 times, given the number of trials(n) and probability(p) of each trial.

The output should contain a numpy array with 10 numbers representing the required binomial distribution.

Sample Input:
0
10
0.5

Expected Output:

[5 6 5 5 5 6 5 7 8 5]

My Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
np.random.seed(0)
seed=int(input())
n=int(input())
p=float(input())
i = 1
while i <= n:
    x = np.random.binomial(n, p)
    s=np.array(x)
    print(s)
    i += 1
```

Code Output:

5
6
5
5
5
6
5
7
8
5

Output is not coming out as desired what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What's the difference between the expected output and your actual output? The square brackets?

Comment: @Anakhand 
yes true

Answer (score 3):

Try this which generates 10 binomial RVs without a loop:

```
import numpy as np
n = 8
p = 0.1
np.random.seed(0)
s = np.random.binomial(n, p, 10)
print(s)
# array([0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0])
```

Comment: i get the following output which is not what i want

[5 6 5 5 5 6 5 7 8 5]
[6 5 5 7 3 3 2 7 6 7]
[8 6 5 6 3 6 3 7 5 5]
[4 6 5 5 2 5 5 5 7 6]
[4 5 6 3 6 6 4 3 4 4]
[5 5 8 3 4 3 6 4 5 4]
[3 3 6 3 4 4 6 3 7 3]
[8 5 8 5 6 2 4 3 4 3]
[4 5 3 6 5 4 5 3 5 7]
[4 6 3 6 4 4 5 2 7 1]

Comment: @user10528004 Have you run this code as-is, outside of any loop?

Comment: you need to use it without a loop, it gives you 10 RVs, you don't need a loop

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the original input value, please find the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
np.random.seed(0)
seed=int(input())
n=int(input())
p=float(input())
# Above code has been taken from the original requester as using the above input 
# output will be generated
npr = 10
np.random.seed(seed) 
s = np.random.binomial(n, p, npr)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
np.random.seed(0)
s=np.random.binomial(n,p,10)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np 

seed=int(input())
n=int(input())
p=float(input())

np.random.seed(seed)
s =np.random.binomial(n, p, 10)
print(s)
```

Comment: Please explain how this code is an improvement over the original code

Comment: Please add the relevant context, or comparison.